# How can I create a related entity in a many-to-many relationship with Prisma?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, many-to-many, prisma

i have a problem with prisma.

I'm trying to insert a related entity, but in my case, since it is a many to many relationship, I do not have the id accessible.
I will share the code as I have it and what I am trying to do.

```
model FirstEntity {
  id              Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  secondEntities  SecondEntity []
}

model SecondEntity {
  id            Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  FirstEntities FirstEntity[]
}
```

I am trying to insert a SecondEntity associated directly to a FirstEntity, I have it as follows, although this way it is inserted without being associated.

```
router.post(
    "/",
    async (req, res) => {
      const id  = req.params.id;

      const createdRoad = await prisma.secondEntity.create({
        data: { ...req.body, },
      });
      res.status(200).json(createdRoad);
    }
);
```

I had a similar problem in the get but I solved it in the following way, that's how it works.

```
router.get(
  "/",
  async (req, res) => {
    const id  = req.params.id;
    const workers = await prisma.secondEntity.findMany({
        where: {
            FirstEntities : {
                some: {
                    id: Number(id)
                }
            }
        }
    });
    res.status(200).json(workers);
  }
);
```

Could you help me with this please?
Thank you so much.
Regards.

I am trying to create an entity related to another automatically with prisma, in a many-to-many relationship.